# Css Order does not position correctly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div with two div inside. On the left 70% and on the right 30% in one row at laptop. But at phone size, I want the div no 2 to be on top of div no 1. I have applied the css `order` property but it seems like not working.

```css
/* main container */

#resume {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  background-color: silver
}


/* every section wrapper */

.section {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

section .location {
  margin-right: .5em;
  color: #606d76;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#contact {
  margin-top: .5rem;
}

#profiles .item {
  padding: 0;
}

#header>#profiles,
#header>#contact,
#skills,
#languages,
#interests {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#header>div {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#header>div>div {
  margin-right: 1.2em;
}

#header h1.name {
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 100%;
}

#header h2.label {
  color: #202931;
  font-size: 1.47rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#header .picture {
  width: 11em;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.main-summary {
  background: #f1f8ff;
  padding: 1.2em 1em;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.main-summary p {
  margin: .15em 0 0;
}

h2.section-title {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 1em 0.3em 0;
  color: #ff6d1f;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: none;
  font-size: .9rem;
}

.section>header {
  position: relative;
}

.fa {
  margin-right: 0.25em;
}

.section>header::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: .7em;
  height: 1px;
  background: #ccc;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -100;
  display: block;
}

.section.main-summary>section {
  margin: 0;
}

.section>section>header {
  font-size: 1.38rem;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: .7em;
}

.section>section>header:first-of-type {
  margin: 0;
}

.section>section>header .space-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.56rem;
  top: 5px;
  color: #aaa;
  line-height: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.section header .date {
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: inline-table;
  padding: .1em 0;
  font-weight: 600;
}


/****************
*      PHONE
****************/

@media screen and (min-width: 460px) {
  #resume {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0px auto;
  }
  .display {
    max-width: 180px;
  }
  .child {
    flex: 100%;
  }
  .topper {
    order: 0;
  }
}


/****************
    *       LAPTOP
    ****************/

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
  li {
    margin-left: 1.5em;
  }
  #resume {
    width: 820px;
    margin: 2rem auto;
  }
  .section>section>header .space-left {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .section>section {
    margin-left: 1.67rem;
  }
  .toggle-item {
    transform: translate(-9999px);
  }
  .toggle-item+label {
    display: block;
    margin-top: -16px;
  }
  .toggle-item:checked+label:after {
    content: '\f0d7';
  }
  .toggle-item+label:after {
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: -20px;
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 16px;
    content: '\f0da';
    font-family: Fontawesome;
  }
  .toggle-item~.item {
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .toggle-item:checked~.item {
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .5s linear;
  }
  .company::before,
  .institution::before,
  .organization::before,
  .awarder::before {
    content: "| ";
  }
  .header-left {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    word-break: normal;
  }
  .section header .date {
    float: right;
    padding: .2em;
  }
  .display {
    display: none;
  }
  .display:not(.none) {
    display: block;
  }
  .parent {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
  }
  .child {
    flex: 0 30%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
    order: 1;
  }
  .wider {
    flex: 0 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <title>Steve</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="resume">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child wider">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="child topper">
        2
      </div>
    </div>
    <header class="clear" id="header">
      <div>
        <h1 class="name">Steve</h1>
        <h2 class="label">Programmer</h2>
      </div><span class="location"><span class="address">2712 Broadway St,</span> <span class="postalCode">CA 94115,</span> <span class="city">San Francisco,</span> <span class="region">California</span> <span class="countryCode">US</span></span>
      <div id="contact">
        <div class="website">
          <span class="fa fa-external-link"></span> <a href="http://richardhendricks.com" target="_blank">http://richardhendricks.com</a>
        </div>
        <div class="email">
          <span class="fa fa-envelope-o"></span> <a href="mailto:richard@valley.com">richard@valley.com</a>
        </div>
        <div class="phone">
          <span class="fa fa-mobile"></span> <a href="tel:(912)%20555-4321">(912) 555-4321</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="profiles">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="username">
            <span class="fa fa-twitter twitter social"></span> <span>neutralthoughts</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="username">
            <span class="fa fa-soundcloud soundcloud social"></span> <span class="url"><a href="https://soundcloud.com/dandymusicnl" target="_blank">dandymusicnl</a></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The reason I am doing these two divs so that later I can put a photo in div no 2.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have a ton of time currently, but have you tried changing the direction of the flex from row to column?

Comment: Please, create a [**minimal** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to only show the part you have trouble with.

Comment: as a sidenote: your media queries for phones are a bit to high. There is no phone with more then 480px width in portrait mode. So with 460px you going to miss most cellphones. Smallest media query should start at 320px which is the smallest phone width (iphone). Note that there is a difference between hardware and css pixels for mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are only making the `.parent` class a `flexbox` on a larger screen. You need to make it a `flexbox` on all sizes. You also need to set the `order` to `-1` so that `.topper` will be pulled up.

```css
/* main container */

#resume {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  background-color: silver
}


/* every section wrapper */

.section {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

section .location {
  margin-right: .5em;
  color: #606d76;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#contact {
  margin-top: .5rem;
}

#profiles .item {
  padding: 0;
}

#header>#profiles,
#header>#contact,
#skills,
#languages,
#interests {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#header>div {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#header>div>div {
  margin-right: 1.2em;
}

#header h1.name {
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 100%;
}

#header h2.label {
  color: #202931;
  font-size: 1.47rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#header .picture {
  width: 11em;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.main-summary {
  background: #f1f8ff;
  padding: 1.2em 1em;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.main-summary p {
  margin: .15em 0 0;
}

h2.section-title {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 1em 0.3em 0;
  color: #ff6d1f;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: none;
  font-size: .9rem;
}

.section>header {
  position: relative;
}

.fa {
  margin-right: 0.25em;
}

.section>header::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: .7em;
  height: 1px;
  background: #ccc;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -100;
  display: block;
}

.section.main-summary>section {
  margin: 0;
}

.section>section>header {
  font-size: 1.38rem;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: .7em;
}

.section>section>header:first-of-type {
  margin: 0;
}

.section>section>header .space-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.56rem;
  top: 5px;
  color: #aaa;
  line-height: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.section header .date {
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: inline-table;
  padding: .1em 0;
  font-weight: 600;
}


  .parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
  }


/****************
*      PHONE
****************/

@media screen and (min-width: 460px) {
  #resume {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0px auto;
  }
  .display {
    max-width: 180px;
  }
  .child {
    flex: 100%;
  }
  .topper {
    order: -1;
  }
}


/****************
    *       LAPTOP
    ****************/

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
  li {
    margin-left: 1.5em;
  }
  #resume {
    width: 820px;
    margin: 2rem auto;
  }
  .section>section>header .space-left {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .section>section {
    margin-left: 1.67rem;
  }
  .toggle-item {
    transform: translate(-9999px);
  }
  .toggle-item+label {
    display: block;
    margin-top: -16px;
  }
  .toggle-item:checked+label:after {
    content: '\f0d7';
  }
  .toggle-item+label:after {
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: -20px;
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 16px;
    content: '\f0da';
    font-family: Fontawesome;
  }
  .toggle-item~.item {
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .toggle-item:checked~.item {
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .5s linear;
  }
  .company::before,
  .institution::before,
  .organization::before,
  .awarder::before {
    content: "| ";
  }
  .header-left {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    word-break: normal;
  }
  .section header .date {
    float: right;
    padding: .2em;
  }
  .display {
    display: none;
  }
  .display:not(.none) {
    display: block;
  }
  .parent {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
  }
  .child {
    flex: 0 30%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
    order: 1;
  }
  .wider {
    flex: 0 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <title>Steve</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="resume">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child wider">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="child topper">
        2
      </div>
    </div>
    <header class="clear" id="header">
      <div>
        <h1 class="name">Steve</h1>
        <h2 class="label">Programmer</h2>
      </div><span class="location"><span class="address">2712 Broadway St,</span> <span class="postalCode">CA 94115,</span> <span class="city">San Francisco,</span> <span class="region">California</span> <span class="countryCode">US</span></span>
      <div id="contact">
        <div class="website">
          <span class="fa fa-external-link"></span> <a href="http://richardhendricks.com" target="_blank">http://richardhendricks.com</a>
        </div>
        <div class="email">
          <span class="fa fa-envelope-o"></span> <a href="mailto:richard@valley.com">richard@valley.com</a>
        </div>
        <div class="phone">
          <span class="fa fa-mobile"></span> <a href="tel:(912)%20555-4321">(912) 555-4321</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="profiles">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="username">
            <span class="fa fa-twitter twitter social"></span> <span>neutralthoughts</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="username">
            <span class="fa fa-soundcloud soundcloud social"></span> <span class="url"><a href="https://soundcloud.com/dandymusicnl" target="_blank">dandymusicnl</a></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks it works. After I add the full version of my code, I realize that the mobile version overwrite the laptop version for that two divs. What could be the possible cause of it?